# How to test authentication using Laravel Dusk?

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit, laravel-dusk

I'm setting up e2e tests using Laravel Dusk and I'm having problems trying to figure out how to test Laravel's authentication.

I am migrating a database using `DatabaseMigrations` trait and populating it with 1 record ( running setUp method which mocks up a user ). I tried to login with this specific user using the `loginAs()` method but it doesn't log me in.

My `AuthenticationTest.php` file

```php
  use DatabaseMigrations;
    public function setUp(): void
    {
        parent::setUp();
        factory('App\User')->create();
    }


    public function an_authenticated_user_will_see_an_account_button()
    {
        $this->browse(function (Browser $browser) {
            $browser
                ->loginAs(User::find(1))
                ->visit('http://recipemanager.test/recipes')
                ->assertSee('Account');
        });
    }
```

My `dusk routes`

```
|        | GET|HEAD | _dusk/login/{userId}/{guard?} |                  | Laravel\Dusk\Http\Controllers\UserController@login                     | web          |
|        | GET|HEAD | _dusk/logout/{guard?}         |                  | Laravel\Dusk\Http\Controllers\UserController@logout                    | web          |
|        | GET|HEAD | _dusk/user/{guard?}           |                  | Laravel\Dusk\Http\Controllers\UserController@user                      | web          |
```

## Note that I haven't touched any controllers, files related to Laravel Dusk!

#### I am not using a testing database for my tests and I know that's bad I'm getting into it don't hate me.

Steps to reproduce the bug ( You need to have XAMPP ):

1. [Clone the repo](https://github.com/KristianWEB/recipe-manager/tree/account)

2. Switch to branch `account`

2. Configure the `.env file` to match your database

3. Make sure to configure `vhosts` Apache file and `etc/hosts` file so you can access `recipemanager.test` as home route ( `127.0.0.1 recipemanager.test` )

4. Run `php artisan dusk`

Errors:
`1)Tests\Browser\AuthenticationTest::an_authenticated_user_will_see_an_account_button
Did not see expected text [Account] within element [body].
Failed asserting that false is true.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed the problem by visiting recipes `visit('/recipes')`. The problem was in the environment file -> APP_URL was set to localhost and Dusk was trying to visit localhost:800/recipes. I checked that by asserting full URL

```php
 $this->browse(function (Browser $browser) {
            $browser
                ->loginAs(User::find(1))
                ->visit('/recipes')
                ->assertUrlIs('http://recipemanager.test/recipes');
        });

Error: Actual URL [http://localhost/recipes] does not equal expected URL [http://recipemanager.test/recipes].
```

`.env` file

```
APP_URL=http://localhost
```

After I changed the APP_URL to `http://recipemanager.test` and visit `/recipes` everything is working fine!